# how to do sudo -E ..... in fabric?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, fabric

I have a fabric script that currently uses commands such as:

```
sudo('pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors')
```

what i want to know is how do i pass sudo the -E option, to run this?

```
sudo -E pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors
```

EDIT:

tried this:

```
sudo('pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors, -E')
```

but that seems to pass the option to pip install instead of sudo

EDIT 2:

```
env.sudo_prefix = "sudo -E -S -p '%(sudo_prompt)s'"
```

is giving me a TypreError: format requires a mapping

EDIT 3:

```
env.sudo_prefix = "sudo -E -S -p '%(sudo_prompt)s'" % env
```

is giving me a TypreError: not all arguments converted during string formating

Comment: Can you try : env.sudo_prefix = "sudo -E -S -p '%s' "

Comment: that runs but doesnt seem to override the original sudo_prefix, it brings me back to the original error i was getting, a return error of 1 when running the pip install code

Answer (score 1):

From the fabric source file . the sudo method signature is as follows :

```
def sudo(command, shell=True, pty=True, combine_stderr=None, user=None,
    quiet=False, warn_only=False, stdout=None, stderr=None, group=None,
    timeout=None):
```

the examples provided do not show any such scenario (amazingly) i would have bet otherwise.

```
sudo("~/install_script.py")
        sudo("mkdir /var/www/new_docroot", user="www-data")
        sudo("ls /home/jdoe", user=1001)
        result = sudo("ls /tmp/")
        with settings(sudo_user='mysql'):
            sudo("whoami") # prints 'mysql'
```

I would suggest you supply the user key.

Have a look at this open ticket :

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/503

Have your tried running ur command with run()

```
run('sudo -E pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors')
```

Comment: I have also found [sudo_prefix](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/env.html?highlight=options) but havent got it working yet

Comment: run('sudo -E pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors') seems to work on my host machine but when i run it from my 'ubuntu-server' virtualbox it returns with an error code 1

Comment: env.sudo_prefix = "sudo -E -S -p '%(sudo_prompt)s' " % env

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty bad idea, it would force you to store passwords clear text and so on. The right™ way of doing it is running

```
$ sudo visudo
```

and configuring sudo to allow your user to run pip without prompting for a password.

Otherwise you're creating a number of security problems.

Comment: the way i am currently running it i use: sudo('pip install virtualenv --upgrade --use-mirrors') only requires the user to put their password in the first time and does not code in the password